# Why do I get this Error message?

Tags: permissions

Why do I get the following error message:

```
josef@josef-Satellite-L755:~$ apt-get install -f
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
josef@josef-Satellite-L755:~$
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: IF you read the message it tells you the problem - "are you root?" . Two most common problems are 1. you are not running the command with sudo or 2. another program is running and accessing the file, package manager for example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to preface your command with `sudo` and enter your password when prompted.